# posting on facebook wall with picture

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there any restrictions of pictures that I can post on someones wall inside message?

When I use this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['publish'])){
        try {
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "I love thinkdiff.net for facebook app development tutorials. <img src="http://c3354688.r88.cf0.rackcdn.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley"> ",
                'link'    => 'http://ithinkdiff.net',
                'picture' => 'http://thinkdiff.net/ithinkdiff.png',
                'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
                'description'=> 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
                )
            );
            //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine but if I change picture to different URL photo ist presented despite the fact that picture is available.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what the different URL is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/
on the domain and see what comes back ?
Maybe you need to clear FB's cache.